# SQL usermapping for Farm-account: dbo vs itself

Tags: security, sql-server, configuration

On my SharePoint farm (in SQL) the farm-account is sometimes mapped as user (itself) to a SharePoint database and sometimes the farm-account is mapped as `dbo` to a database.

On all databases the farm-account has the `db_owner` role.

It this a problem?, shouldn't it all be `dbo`?

On the databases where the user is mapped to itself, the owner (via Properties of the database) is set to some other user (seems to be the user that installed SharePoint).

[image]